# Inserting column with insert method of pandas dataframe generating error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have below code

I am trying to insert new columns as specific positions with `insert` method. Below is my code,

```
import pandas as pd

(pd.DataFrame({'product name': ['laptop', 'printer', 'printer',], 'price': [1200, 150, 1200],  'price1': [1200, 150, 1200]})
    .insert(0, 'AAA', -1)
    .insert(1, 'BBB', -2)
)
```

With this I am getting below error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'insert'
>>>
```

Could you please help to resolve this error.

Any pointer is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Cause of the error

`DataFrame.insert` is the **inplace** operation which modifies the original dataframe and returns `None`. After calling the first `insert` operation the return value is `None` hence the next `insert` throws an error complaining that `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'insert'`.

### Solution

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'product name': ['laptop', 'printer', 'printer',], 'price': [1200, 150, 1200],  'price1': [1200, 150, 1200]})
df.insert(0, 'AAA', -1)
df.insert(1, 'BBB', -2)
```

### Hacky solution

```
df.pipe(lambda x: x.insert(0, 'AAA', -1) or x.insert(1, 'BBB', -2) or x)
```

Answer (score 0):

The insert method doesn't return a dataframe object. You can assign the dataframe object to a variable and apply the insert method to the variable:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'product name': ['laptop', 'printer', 'printer',],
                   'price': [1200, 150, 1200],
                   'price1': [1200, 150, 1200]})
df.insert(0, 'AAA', -1)
df.insert(1, 'BBB', -2)
```

You can also use join to have it within the chain, but you have to know the number of rows:

```
pd.DataFrame({'AAA': [-1] * 3})\
    .join(pd.DataFrame({'BBB': [-2] * 3}))\
    .join(pd.DataFrame({'product name': ['laptop', 'printer', 'printer', ],
                        'price': [1200, 150, 1200],
                        'price1': [1200, 150, 1200]}))
```

Comment: Thanks. But I am looking for some way if I could use `insert` within the `chain`

Comment: I've edited my answer to apply the chaining you are looking for but it uses join rather than insert because insert doesn't return an object.